# SQL Subquery Column Where Name Contains a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to code a certain subquery. I keep getting the "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error. I need to query the description of a parent order instead of the child.

**Example:**
Parent Order: 100-01
Child Orders: 100-02, 100-03
Each order has a description. But in one column I need the description of the parent:

```
WHERE [ORDER] LIKE '%-01'
```

Current code is below:

```
SELECT  NAME as [Job],
        [Master Job Desc] = (SELECT TOP 1 [DESCR] FROM TABLE WHERE [NAME] LIKE '%-01'),
        LEFT(or_order.descr,30) as [Description],
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY OR_ORDER.DELIVERY asc, or_op.STARTSEC asc
```

Any advice? Thanks

EDIT: I forgot, I've already tried adding TOP 1 to the subquery, but it just returns the same value for the entire column. I do not want that, I want to find the parent job order.

EDIT2: Here is the separate SQL for what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT [DESCR] FROM [Or_Order] WHERE [NAME] LIKE '%-01'
```

The above statements returns descriptions where the name contains the parent job number (-01). I need that in a single column.

Comment: How are these orders named? Are the numbers before the hyphen a unique transaction number and the 01, 02, etc the line/child number?

Comment: It seems to me like you are struggling here because your data violates 1NF by stuffing two data points into a single column. This would be much easier if those two values were in two columns instead of two values in one column. If at all possible you should change the design...of course this isn't always possible and we have to wrestle decisions made previously that are less than optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`charindex()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to get the parent part of the order (up to the hyphen) and concatenate that with '01'. With that, you can join to the same table to get the parent order description.

```
select
      Job = c.Name
    , [Master Job Desc] = p.Descr
    , [Description] = left(c.descr,30) 
  from or_order as c
    left join or_order as p 
      on left(c.[order],charindex('-',c.[Order]))+'01' = p.[Order]
  order by delivery asc, or_op.startsec asc
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/GSN90790

```
create table or_order (
    [order] varchar(32)
  , Name varchar(32)
  , Descr varchar(32)
);

insert into or_order values 
    ('100-01','Name 1','Descr 1')
  , ('100-02','Name 2','Descr 2')
  , ('100-03','Name 3','Descr 3');

select
    Job = c.Name
  , [Master Job Desc] = p.Descr
  , [Description] = left(c.descr,30) 
  from or_order as c
    left join or_order as p 
      on left(c.[order],charindex('-',c.[Order]))+'01' = p.[Order]
```

results:

```
+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|  Job   | Master Job Desc | Description |
+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| Name 1 | Descr 1         | Descr 1     |
| Name 2 | Descr 1         | Descr 2     |
| Name 3 | Descr 1         | Descr 3     |
+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: @Datallboy Added a test to show you what I meant. Looks like I confused a column named `order` with the column `name`.

Comment: They are `aliases` for the table names (the same table in this case).